# Unable to add duplicate customers to Quickbooks using QBFC

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I have the following code:

```
public void addCustomer()
        {
            bool sessionBegun = false;
            bool connectionOpen = false;
            QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;

            try
            {
                //Create sessions manager object
                sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();

                //Create the message set request object to hold our request
                IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0);
                requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

                //Connect to quickbooks and begin a session
                sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "CSW QB Interface");
                connectionOpen = true;
                sessionManager.BeginSession(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Intuit\QuickBooks\Company Files\Super Legit Industries.qbw", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
                sessionBegun = true;

                ICustomerAdd customerAddRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerAddRq();
                customerAddRq.Name.SetValue("Test Customer 1");

                //Send the request and get the response from quickbooks
                IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
                IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
                ICustomerRet customerRet = (ICustomerRet)response.Detail;

                //Console.WriteLine(response.Detail.ToString());
                custID = customerRet.ListID.GetValue();

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //End the session and close the connection to quickbooks
                if(sessionBegun)
                {
                    sessionManager.EndSession();
                }
                if(connectionOpen)
                {
                    sessionManager.CloseConnection();
                }
            }
        }
```

My issue is that there could be a case where two people have the same name and need to be entered into quickbooks, but if I run this code more than once (trying to add "Test Customer 1" more than once), the second time I throws an error on the line:

```
custID = customerRet.ListID.GetValue();
```

Saying:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Is there any way to add a duplicate customer into QB using QBFC without it throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is that there could be a case where two people have the same name and need to be entered into quickbooks,

QuickBooks itself does not support having two customers with the same name.

What you're running into is not a limitation of QBFC, or the SDK, or anything really - this is how QuickBooks works. You can't have duplicates.